# Flash as3 event listener for when a movieclip is stopped

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm thinking of making a movieclip which stops itself at certain points (just with stop(); at certain keyframes in the movieclip timeline), then the user is prompted to continue the clip.

What is the best why to listen for the stopping of the movieclip? I think I want an event listener that detects when the movieclip is stopped, but I don't know if there is one.

Many thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you have to manually stop a MovieClip via `stop()` you can easily manually dispatch your own event on the same frame using [`dispatchEvent()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/IEventDispatcher.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#dispatchEvent%28%29)

For example, on a frame you could have:

```
stop();
dispatchEvent(
    new Event("movieclip_stopped");
);
```

And the listener for that MovieClip would be:

```
myMovie.addEventListener("movieclip_stopped", _stopHandler);
function _stopHandler(e:Event):void
{
    trace('mc was stopped');
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marty, this worked perfectly!

I'm new to Flash but I'm wondering why this method I thought of just now doesn't work:

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkstop);


function checkstop(evt:Event):void
{
 if (mymovieclip.isPlaying == false)
  trace("stopped playing");
}

Am I misunderstanding what the isPlaying property does?

Comment: Looking here (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6) I don't even see an `isPlaying` property.

Answer (score 2):

there's an undocumented feature you could use; addFrameScript(a function of MovieClip); which, as the name suggest, adds code to a certain frame. This way you don't need a framelistener, and you can dynamically add code to a keyframe. So knowing when the movieclip reached its end would be;

```
mc.addFrameScript(mc.totalFrames - 1, onMcEnded);
function onMcEnded():void {
    trace("last frame of movieclip");
}
```

if you want to make a movieclip which has certain labels, and then acts on those labels, one way would be to do it like this.(I guess this is pretty common code for anyone who doesn't want to add code directly on the timeline)

let's say you added two labels on the timeline: askUser1 and askUser2

the way to add interaction on those labels would be like so:

```
for each(var frameLabel:FrameLabel in mc.currentLabels) {
      configureLabel(frameLabel.name,frameLabel.frame-1)                
}

protected function configureLabel(labelName:String,labelFrame:int):void 
{
    switch(labelName) {                 
        case "askUser1" :
                mc.addFrameScript(labelFrame, onAskUser1);
        break;                  
        case "askUser2" :   
                mc.addFrameScript(labelFrame, onAskUser2);
        break;
    }           
}
private function onAskUser1():void{
     //do stuff for askUser1 Label
}
private function onAskUser2():void{
     //do stuff for askUser2 Label
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Horrendously hacky solution is to listen constantly for `onEnterFrame`:

```
var isPlaying:Boolean = false;
var lastFrame:int = 0;
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, function(event:Event):void
{
    isPlaying = (lastFrame != currentFrame);
    lastFrame = currentFrame;
});
```

Better solution is to actually track the state based on your `stop()` code.

Answer (score 0):

Hey [user1010076](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1010076/user1010076) I don't know how you got the code from Marty to work ..

```
stop();
dispatchEvent(
    new Event("movieclip_stopped");
);
```

I tried and tried and then found this one liner from [Introduction to event handling in ActionScript 3.0](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/articles/event_handling_as3.html)

```
target.dispatchEvent(new Event("type"));
```

So for to have Marty's entire code to work, you would need ..

```
myMovie.dispatchEvent(new Event("movieclip_stopped"));
```

I have a similar use case to yours and the code now works with the "target" added whereas I did not without it.

Comment: Hey Randy I've been trying to find the file I put the code in but no success so far. I did make a new file and try it out though - it worked with dispatchEvent(new Event("hello there")); in the MovieClip (called mymovieclip), and with mymovieclip.addEventListener(Event, "hello there"); in the main timeline. But now I'm not sure why you need the mymovieclip. part in the main time, because the event should bubble anyway...

Comment: Sorry. Just found your reply, and thank you. @ the time of post I was aching to know how you got to work what I did not. All I know is I did need the target prefix before the dispatchEvent. Do want to understand stuff but seems sometimes cannot. Good thing here is 2 ways to try!
**Good luck** [user1010076](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1010076/user1010076)